# Prehilbert space theorem

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ prehilbert space and $Y$ be a Banach subspace of $X$ and let $x$ belong to $X$ and the vector $p(x)$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ on $Y$ .
Prove that:

1. $x-p(x)$ belong to the orthogonal complement of $Y$ ($Y$ perpendicular).
   Any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that a vector $u$ is in the orthogonal complement of $Y$, you need to show that $\langle u,y \rangle = 0$ for an arbitrary $y\in Y$.

You've defined $p(x)$ as the vector in $Y$ minimizing distance to $x$. Use this definition to show that $\langle p(x)-x,y\rangle=0$ for all $y\in Y$: if otherwise, you would be able to construct a vector in $Y$ even closer to $x$.

Comment: I started from here but i dont know how to contiue

Comment: What have you taken to be the definition of "orthogonal projection"?

Comment: <x,y>-<p(x),y>  plz show me some details

Comment: The definition: p(x) = inf{||x-u||, u belong to Y }

Comment: That's a number, not a vector.

Comment: Sry, I mean ||x-p(x)|| not p(x)